# How to flip the last character of a string

Tags: awk

I am trying to flip the last character of the string between 1 and 2. I need to understand why `system2` is able to convert into `system1` , however `system1` is not able to convert into `system2` ?

```
echo system2|awk -vFS="" '{if($NF==1) {gsub($NF,2) };if($NF==2)gsub($NF,1)}1'
system1
echo system1|awk -vFS="" '{if($NF==1) {gsub($NF,2) };if($NF==2)gsub($NF,1)}1'
system1
```

Also , is there any smarter way of doing this flip ?

Comment: Why would you need `awk` for this? The shell built-ins can be used very well for this

Comment: You have a lot of awk answers that are relying on setting FS to null splitting the input into characters. That's undefined behavior per POSIX and so it'll do that in some awks while in other awks it'll leave the input as a single line in 1 field and in other awks still it could do anything else and still be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you change the $NF to 2 which makes the second condition true and it gets changed back to 1 again. You need an `else`.

```
awk -vFS="" '{if($NF==1) {gsub($NF,2) }else if($NF==2)gsub($NF,1)}1'
```

I can think of a bit simpler solution in sed:

```
sed 's/1$/2/;t;s/2$/1/'
```

which uses the `t` command that (if no label was specified) goes to the end of the script if the previous substitution was successful.

Another possible solution uses Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/([12])$/ $1 =~ tr=12=21=r /e'
```

Which matches the final 1 or 2 and runs a transliteration on it. You can use a similar trick with `tr` in the shell:

```
printf '%s' ${string:0:-1}
printf '%s\n' ${string: -1} | tr 12 21
```

Without shelling out, you can use for example parameter expansion and arithmetics:

```
if [[ $string = *[12] ]] ; then
   echo ${string%[12]}$((3-${string: -1}))
else
    echo $string
fi
```

Comment: That awk script is a bad one. For a start it's relying on setting FS to null splitting the string into character but that's undefined bahavior per POSIX so it'll actually do different things in different awks. Then if it DOES split the input into characters it's going to replace **every occurrence** of the last character across the whole line with either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

To do this concisely, robustly and portably with any awk would be:

```
$ echo system2| awk '!sub(/1$/,2){sub(/2$/,1)}1'
system1
$ echo system1| awk '!sub(/1$/,2){sub(/2$/,1)}1'
system2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try following(OP's attempt's correction).

```
echo system1|awk -vFS="" '{if($NF==1){gsub($NF,2);print;next};if($NF==2)gsub($NF,1)}1'
```

***Why OP's attempt is not working:***

Since first condition is TRUE and $NF is `1` it is changing it to `2` now 2nd condition is TRUE and `2` is again substituted to `1` so hence it is giving same output.

***My attempt for solving this problem will be:*** Since OP's attempted code is very specific to GNU `awk`, so we could try following which could be more generic solution.

```
echo system1 | 
awk '
{
   val=substr($0,length($0))
   printf("%s%s\n",substr($0,1,length($0)-1),val==1+0?2:(val==2?1:val))
   val=""
}'
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for both the inputs (it has the same problem but for the other input).

Comment: @choroba, thanks sir for letting know, changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}($NF==1||$NF==2){$NF=$NF%2+1}1'
```

This is similar to oguzismail's approach.

- Only alters if last char is `1` or `2`.
- `1 % 2 + 1` = `2`, and `2 % 2 + 1` = `1`.